# how to change toolbar image in ios6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

i'm pretty new to iOS programming. How do i change the image for each of the items in toolbar as shown on the picture below. The toolbar is on the bottom of the screen. Thanks in advance. [image: toolbar]

Comment: in your toolbar its ther 4 barbutton right...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change or modify the tab bar items in anyway it is very possible. here is the link to ray's tutorial of how to change the images and colors of the `uitabbar` items and even tab bar itself. hope it help you. also you can explore ray's site for more info in ios development . it has been very helpful to me. happy coding.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating your UITabBarController in code, see the methods on UITabBarItem itself.  Specifically, `finishedSelectedImage` and `finishedUnselectedImage`

If you are creating your UITabBarController in Interface Builder, look for the "Image" dropdown in the Attributes inspector, while you have the Tab Bar Item selected.

[image]

Comment: i tried this method but the images above the item names are not resized properly, it is shown on the picture i uploaded.